# Error while installing sentry on server python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, sentry

I looked up all over the google, installed many packages.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config 
python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7
 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test 
 libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 
 python-dev
```

The traceback of error is:

```
Collecting symsynd<4.0.0,>=3.0.0 (from sentry)
Using cached symsynd-3.0.0.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Qunused-arguments’
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-FnsY4d/symsynd/setup.py", line 109, in <module>
    'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules'
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 268, in __init__
    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_eggs
    replace_conflicting=True,
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 830, in resolve
    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1075, in best_match
    return self.obtain(req, installer)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1087, in obtain
    return installer(requirement)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 380, in fetch_build_egg
    return cmd.easy_install(req)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 629, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 659, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 842, in install_eggs
    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1070, in build_and_install
    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
  File "/www/sentry/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1058, in run_setup
    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-FnsY4d/symsynd

I think like something with gcc, I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, pip 7.0.1, python 2.7.

Please, help! I am looking for answer for a long time

Comment: On their documentation they indicate as a prerequisite `pip 8.1+`: https://docs.sentry.io/server/installation/python/ (they also indicate that installing with python is deprecated, you might want to switch to the docker install)

Comment: @Adonis thanks, installed with docker)